# How to enhance gold material and rendering for a jewelry

Tags: rendering, materials

for a month I have been trying to  find proper gold material for my jewelry rendering but nothing that I found was suitable. I am looking for a really realistic gold material with scratches. Any gold material I use or try just looks so unnatural and so perfect. Additionally, can anyone give me a tip to enhance rendering my jewelry? Thank you. The pictures show the process I am currently now.

[image]

Comment: Hello, maybe share your object and also an image reference of the kind of material you would like to see? Maybe your current material is not glossy enough or needs some bumps or some variations on its reflectivity?

Comment: Lots of tutorials on making procedural gold materials out there, for instance https://youtu.be/S_sxWoFl4_s by PIXXO 3D and https://youtu.be/XXZtuPVTU6o?list=PLsGl9GczcgBs6TtApKKK-L_0Nm6fovNPk by Ryan King.